# Mobile app installed or not using ampscript

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, ios, android

Our systems sending promotional email to customers. In the email there are links about promotion. We are also maintaining mobile app (ios and android) for promotions. We are writing an ampscript to redirect from the promotional emails to mobile app or web site. The scenario is like follows,

If clicking in the email link from windows machine, it should show the web page that describes the details of the promotions.
If clicking in the email link from mobile and the myapp is installed in the mobile, it should go the myapp page of the mobile app. (like myappapp://)
If clicking in the email link from mobile and myapp is not installed in the mobile the it should go to the web page that shows details of the promotions.
In the scenario#3, it displays the corresponding appstore page if myapp is not installed in the mobile.

Is there any mechanism to check the myapp is installed or not from the ampscript itself?

Anybody can help

Answer (score 1):

AMPscript is a server-side language and therefore is completed prior to the receipt of the email by the subscriber. Due to this, you are unable to use it to gather any data from the subscriber outside what you have stored prior to send.

Your best bet is to use a service like Live Clicker's Realtime Email (http://www.realtime.email/) to accomplish your job. Even that is not a guaranteed result, but should provide most of the functionality you are looking for.

ref: http://help.exacttarget.com/AMPscript/